# Constantly updating message box within easygui multenterbox

Tags: python, user-interface, user-input, easygui

I am coding up some request form, which will be typed in by user. The two boxes that are displayed are shown below:

[image]

The input box is generated using the following lines:

```
fieldNames= ['','']
fieldNames= ['START DEPTH','END DEPTH']
inputs  = easygui.multenterbox ('Please fill the inputs', 'START and END', fieldNames, fieldNames)
```

One thing that I have a problem with is that I want the difference between those two inputs (end depth and start depth) to be found and displayed on this box, something like that:

[image]

Is there a functionality within `easygui` to do so?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @cbracketdash nope(